# Ubuntu only: Nested span, vertical-align: top and font-size doesn't play well together

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, vertical-alignment, font-size

This is really beyond me. Please see the snippet below.

When there are nested spans, and vertical-align set to top, **and** font-size is small (less than 14px), it displays wrongly where the text in outer span is pushed downwards.

Here's what I see, running Xubuntu 14.04 + Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit):
[image: problem0]
[image: problem]

If I change font-size to above 20px, the problem is gone.

But I do need both vertical-align and font-size to be there.

What gives??

## Update:

I switch to a Windows host + Chrome and problem disappeared.
Seems this is a Xubuntu, or gnome, or xfce thing.

```css
.classA, .classB {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px;
  
    /* cosmetic. just to make the illustration clearer */
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<span class="classA">textA <span class="classB">textB</span> textC</span><br>
<span class="classA">textA textC</span>
```

Comment: What is the problem here? It looks as expected for all font sizes. Can you put two screenshots of how it looks like to you and what you want to get?

Comment: same results for me if i put 20px, what's the problem ? and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @John See screenshot attached

Comment: lol i dont see that problem in my screen like i said before it's working fine for me

Comment: @skobaljic do you see what I see?

Comment: It looks fine on windows.

Comment: @Nenad - that's true, Ubuntu is good for development, but not relevant for testing. Its usage is less than 1% on Internet, guess all developers.

Comment: This looks fine to me and I am using the same version of Ubuntu and Chrome as you are.